# .htaccess redirect based on multiple conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to configure a .htaccess RewriteRule and i'm struggling.

I have a domain `www.domain.com`

I'm trying to add these conditions.

I'm working on `www.domain.com/.htaccess`

```
if URL is www.domain.com with no path to file, redirect to www.domain.co.uk

if URL is www.domain.com AND has a path to file, no rewrite, allow.

if URL is www.domain.com AND has a path to file AND file doesnt exist, return 404

if URL points to a directory, return access forbidden
```

They are my requirments.

I've tried multiple things. Heres my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code satisfies the first constraint.

However i have no idea how to check if a path exists, if the path is valid, or if its a directory.

A perfect answer would be code satisfying all the constraints and explainatoin how it works.

I've read the mod_rewrite documentation more times than I care to admit :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Make sure / redirected to other domain
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.domain.co.uk [R=301,L]

# Make sure directory listings are forbidden
Options -Indexes
```

Note that you can use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), which is actually preferred over rewriting in this case

and there is no need to handle files at all in your case - if the URI is not /, then the rules do not apply and regular file handling will be performed (404 error if not found, etc... )